# How may I -from SQL Server Express Ping a network devices and send the query results by email?

Tags: c#, sql-server

How may I -from SQL Server Express Ping a  network devices and send the query results by email ?

```
  USE Retail2018
    GO
        Declare @IP as nchar(100), @enter code hereEmailPerson nchar(40), @result int, 
    @CmdTxt varchar(100), @Comment varchar(1000)
        Create table #
    Temp(Data varchar(1000))
        DECLARE ShopDevices  CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  IP
    FROM ShopDevices11 left join Site  on ShopDevices11.SiteId=Site.SiteId
    where AllowLogin=1 
        OPEN ShopDevices  
    FETCH NEXT FROM ShopDevices INTO  @IP
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
                set @CmdTxt = 'ping ' + @IP
            EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @CmdTxt, no_output
              insert into #Temp  EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @CmdTxt, no_output
                  IF (@result = 1)
              begin
    Set @Comment = 'ShopDevices ' + char(34) + ltrim(rtrim(@IP)) + char(34) + 
    ' - Contact failed, posibil dispozitiv neconectat'

Print @Comment
declare EmailList cursor for
select EmailAddress from EmailAddresses 
open EmailList
fetch next from EmailList
into @EmailPerson
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--SQL Profile Name
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'TestMail',
@recipients = @EmailPerson,
@body = @Comment,
@subject = @Comment      
fetch next from EmailList
into @EmailPerson      
end
CLOSE EmailList
DEALLOCATE EmailList
end

FETCH NEXT FROM ShopDevices
into @IP
END
    CLOSE ShopDevices
DEALLOCATE ShopDevices
  select * from #Temp 
drop table #Temp
GO
```

Comment: If the code you've posted doesn't work, then what error do you get? And.. why would you want to do this from a database?!

Comment: You struggle because you are using the wrong tool. Does tsql have any native support for network communcation? No - that is a clue that you have no choice but to go "outside" of the sql server instance to accomplish your task. So attempting to write a tsql script to do this will be exceptionally difficult and will involve external tools.

Comment: And do not confuse a successful ping with some sort of "working" state. Presumably you do this because these machines should be running some process / app that communicates with the server instance. The ping will only indicate that the machine is reachable in the network, not that your process/app is running and is responsive.